# Create your own custom data type

Tags: c#, generics, types

How can I create a custom made data type in C# that can then be used as a Generic type?
For instance, I would like to create a 1, 3 or 6-bytes data types.

Say we want to represent a memory of some sorts. A memory can be of various types, RAM, EEPROM, etc. The word size contained by a given memory can be 1-byte, 3-bytes or 6-bytes. Now we have:

```
// Note: T could be UInt8, UInt24 or UInt48
class Memory<T>
{    
    // List of words filling up the memory
    public List<Word<T>> Words { get; set; }
    ...    
}

class Word<T>
{       

    // That might be a way to access the data?
    public byte[] Value { get; set; }
    // Should rather be:
    // public T Value { get; set; }

    public Word()
    {
        // Allocate bytes to "Value" based on word type
        List<byte> tmpList = new List<byte>();

        for(int i = 0; i < "sizeOf(T)";) 
            tmpList.Add(0);

        Value = tmpList.ToArray();
    }
}
```

I originally tried with an enum, but not a good way of doing it:

```
public enum WordTypes: IConvertible
{
    /// <summary>One byte per word</summary>        
    [Description("One byte per word")]
    UInt8 = 8,
    /// <summary>Three bytes per word</summary>
    [Description("Three bytes per word")]
    UInt24 = 24,
    /// <summary>Six bytes per word</summary>
    [Description("Six bytes per word")]
    UInt48 = 48
}
```

I also thought of using un-managed memory as it is byte accessible and provides a better representation of the data in memory, but it might be overkill.

### EDIT

Great pointer provided by @JeremyCaney [here](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/int16.cs).

Comment: Any type could used with genric. Could you specify what you mean wit 2-bytes 4-bytes data type?
Probbably use an short (2 bytes) / int (4 bytes)

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem!  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Please, share your code

Comment: While any type can be used in a generic, as per @Genfood’s note, it sounds like you may want to look into creating [value types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-types) and, specifically, structs. Structs are light-weight, immutable classes, and what many of the built-in CLR types are based on.

Comment: @jason.kaisersmith: Or a homework problem. They often look the same.

Comment: @JeremyCaney,not sure how to use that in my scenario, I will give it a go, thanks

Comment: Aside, should clarify: Strictly speaking, structs are not classes. They’re a separate data structure.

Comment: You may also want to cross-reference the reference source code for e.g. [`Int16`](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/int16.cs) or [`SByte`](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/sbyte.cs) as a good example of basic structs that support byte counts.

Comment: @JeremyCaney, awesome, I was just about to ask which properties had to be overriden :-) That helps a lot. That looks huge though!

Comment: @JeremyCaney, so ideally, following this approach, you would recompile the entire Microsoft system library? That might be overkill?

Comment: Like a basic class, a basic struct _can_ be quite simple. The out-of-the-box structs are a lot more complicated because they have many comparers, converters, and parsers. You probably won’t need most of that. Microsoft has a good [introduction to writing structs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/struct).

Answer (score 1):

Based on Jeremy's link, you could do something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Diagnostics.Contracts;

namespace WordTypes
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [Serializable]
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]

    public struct UInt24 : IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible
    {
        internal uint m_value;

        public static explicit operator UInt24(uint v) => new UInt24(v);

        public const uint MaxValue = (uint)0xFFFFFF;
        public const short MinValue = unchecked((short)0x000000);

        public UInt24(uint v)
        {
            if (v > MaxValue)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(v), $"Value too big - Max is {MaxValue}.");
            }
            if (v < MinValue)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(v), $"Value too small - Min is {MinValue}.");
            }

            this.m_value = v;
        }

        // Implement other required IComparable, IFormattable and IConvertible as needed here
        ....

    }
}
```

The key is in the explicit operator that will be used in order to compare against Min/Max defined values and throw an error if boundaries are not respected - Note this is a runtime error!
You then use it as such:

```
Word<UInt24> myWord = new Word<UInt24>();

myWord.Value = (UInt24)0x123456;   // This will work!
myWord.Value = (UInt24)0x1234567;  // This will fail as 0x1234567 > MaxValue!
```

Then do something similar for the other needed data types